# Foreach Конвертация массива string в массив int и подсчёт суммы

Tags: c#, массивы, строки

Всем Привет!

Есть программа которая делает следующее. Разбивает строку “1, 2, 3, 4, 5” и получает массив из этих чисел и находит сумму чисел. Можно использовать только Использовать Split и ConvertToInt32 Цикл Foreach. нужно обойтись без использования LINQ.

Программу я сделал но через цикл for через foreach не получается?? Подскажите пожалуйста как можно поправить код?

```
        string line = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";

        Console.WriteLine(line);

        string[] numbersSt = line.Split(',');

        int[] numbers = new int[numbersSt.Length];

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i =0; i < numbersSt.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(numbersSt[i]);
            sum += numbers[i];
        }

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Массив цифр конвертированных из строки: " + string.Join(" ", numbers));
        Console.WriteLine("Сумма чисел массива " + sum);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Будто кто-то заставляет учить старые технологии, ну ей богу, ибо класс `Convert` уже давно не используется в современных проектах, его аналогом является `int.Parse()`/`int.TryParse()`, а LINQ, ну серьезно, такая задача решается одной строкой благодаря ему (замена вашим 15-ти строкам). А по поводу вашего кода, что то я не пойму, а на кой фиг вам массив чисел (`numbers`), а также это: `string.Join(" ", numbers)`, если у вас уже есть входная строка (`line`)?

Comment: >Я студент заочник 2 курс, нам дали 40 задач и лекции к ним для получения зачета с оценкой, их нужно сделать до 31 января

>задание дословно звучит вот так
Разбить строку “1, 2, 3, 4, 5” и получить массив из этих чисел и найти их сумму. Использовать Split и ConvertToInt32.

>А по поводу вашего кода, что то я не пойму, а на кой фиг вам массив чисел (numbers), а также это: string.Join(" ", numbers), если у вас уже есть входная строка (line)?

>Поясните пожалуйста?

Comment: Значит учат вас по программе 90-х годов, что плачевно... Пояснить? Да пожалуйста: `получить массив из этих чисел` - вы массив получаете при разбитие и дублировать его только с другим типом это нерационально, да тут зависит от понимания "чисел", если понимать под "числом" - `int`, то да, надо конвертировать, если же понимать "число" - как некое значение, то `string` типа достаточно. Исходя из этого "найти сумму" - вам достаточно `foreach (var value in numbersSt) sum += Convert.ToInt32(value);`, если все же нам нужен `int` __массив__, то тут `foreach` бессмысленно использовать, ибо нужен индекс.

Comment: Кстати, если вы "дословно" дали задание, то в нем я не вижу ограничений на массив (коллекция в какой то степени тоже массив), не вижу ограничений на LINQ (в те года его в помине не было) и не вижу других ограничений. Так что вы уверены, что правильно поняли задачу? Может все же `var result = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5".Split(',').Select(int.Parse).Sum();`?)

Comment: спасибо что пояснили
Ограничения преподаватель поставил словами на консультации
вот скрин из методички по которой делаем http://joxi.ru/DrlJ9qki00Q8l2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string line = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";

Console.WriteLine(line);

string[] numbersSt = line.Split(',');

int[] numbers = new int[numbersSt.Length];

int sum = 0, index = 0;

foreach(var ch in numbersSt)
{
    numbers[index] = Convert.ToInt32(ch);
    sum += numbers[index];
    index++;
}       

Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Массив цифр конвертированных из строки: " + string.Join(" ", numbers));
Console.WriteLine("Сумма чисел массива " + sum);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Денис Спасибо большое за помощь!!!!! Лучи благодарности!!!!